# rw_semaphore blocking I/O heavy threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, semaphore

I'm having some trouble tracing the performance bottleneck in my application. I'm doing computations on GPU and I'm using several threads to load and prepare the data. All files are stored on an SSD, but sometimes the performance is drastically reduced (vmstat shows that reads go from 300MB/s down to 30MB/s). When I ran `ps` I noticed that most worker threads are regularly blocked on `call_rwsem_down_write_failed` or on `call_rwsem_down_read_failed`. The actual output was:

```
-     - user   Dl   47.4 -               call_rwsem_down_read_failed
-     - user   Rl   48.5 -               -
-     - user   Dl   48.5 -               call_rwsem_down_write_failed
-     - user   Dl   47.2 -               call_rwsem_down_read_failed
-     - user   Dl   46.8 -               call_rwsem_down_write_failed
-     - user   Dl   49.1 -               call_rwsem_down_write_failed
-     - user   Dl   46.8 -               call_rwsem_down_write_failed
-     - user   Dl   47.2 -               call_rwsem_down_write_failed
-     - user   Dl   46.9 -               call_rwsem_down_write_failed
-     - user   Dl   49.3 -               call_rwsem_down_read_failed
-     - user   Dl   47.2 -               call_rwsem_down_write_failed
-     - user   Dl   48.4 -               call_rwsem_down_write_failed
```

What's strange is that the application is using Torch7 and libpng to load images, but neither of them uses `rw_semaphore`s (I've greped the sources). Also, the threads don't perform any writes.

Since I can't find any place where they are used I suspect that it all happens in some syscall (can it be `read`?). Is there any way to check where these semaphores are used and eliminate the blocking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I suspect that it all happens in some syscall (can it be read?)` - Yes, `rw_semaphores` may be used by almost any syscall. But this is **kernel code**, that why you failed to find it in *user space* libraries. As you are *application* writer, you rarely want to descent into the kernel. Use `strace` or similar tools to get place in the *user space* code, where contention occures.

Comment: I tried `strace`, and found out that the only syscalls made are `open`, `fstat`, `read`, `mmap`, `brk` and `close`. I have no idea how this requires the `rw_semaphore`s, so this is why I asked here - I have no idea how can I change my code to make it more efficient without this knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to check where these semaphores are used …?

Provided that your kernel is suitably configured, you can use the [*system request*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) <kbd>w</kbd> - *Display list of blocked (D state) tasks* - on the console or

```
echo w >/proc/sysrq-trigger
dmesg
```

to see the call stack traces.